# List item to list view

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I want to convert this program to dynamic. Get JSON from server and return to list item.

```
public List<Item> getData() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new Item(1, "Everyday" , "$12.00 USD"),
            new Item(2, "Small Porcelain Bowl", "$50.00 USD"),
            new Item(3, "Favourite Board", "$265.00 USD"),
    );
}
```

I parsed the json but return type error.

```
Error:(73, 8) error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to List<Item>
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 13s
>   Information:2 errors

Here my code:

```
 List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        URL arc= new URL(
                "https://arc.000webhostapp.com/data/Cse.json");
        URLConnection tc = arc.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                listItems.add(jo.getString("text"));
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return listItem;
```

Comment: sry i forget to add my complete codes

Comment: That's fine, show us what you've tried, tell us what's not working and I'll upvote and take a look.

Comment: Now check the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared that your function will return a `List` of `Item` objects but instead you're returning a `List` of `String` objects. When parsing the JSON you get from the server you must turn it into the same `Item` objects like you did in the offline version of your code.

Judging by your code the JSON that you download from the server looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Everyday",
        price: "$12.00 USD"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Small Porcelain Bowl",
        price: "$50.00 USD"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Favourite Board",
        price: "$265.00 USD"
    },  
]
```

Your function should then look something like this:

```
public List<Item> getData() {
    List<Item> listItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

    try {
        URL arc= new URL(
                "https://arc.000webhostapp.com/data/Cse.json");
        URLConnection tc = arc.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                listItems.add(new Item(jo.getInt("id"), jo.getString("text"), jo.getString("price")));
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listItems;
}
```